# Lindhard Function for Boson

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, fermi-energy

We know the density-density response for a non-interacting system with electrons is given by
\begin{equation}
\chi(q,\omega)=\sum_{k} \dfrac{f_{k}-f_{k+q}}{\omega+\epsilon_{k}-\epsilon_{k+q}+i\eta}
\end{equation}
We can calculate the $\chi$ exactly at $T=0$ by replacing the $f_{k}=\Theta(\epsilon_{k}-\epsilon_{F})$ (taking the continuum limit by converting the sum to the integral from 0 to $k_{F}$).
Now, if I want to calculate the same for free Bosons, how should I proceed at $T=0$? Any idea for finite temperature calculations?